# Angular material styles do not work correctly

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Just added mat-form-field component into a project

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
```

and that's what I see:

[image]

Also I have a sort header in my table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="announceSortChange($event)">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by number">
              Дата
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date}} </td>
          </ng-container>
        
          <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Заявка </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
          </ng-container>
                   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="showTaskInfo(row)"></tr>
</table>
```

but it does not shows sort direction arrows, instead of this it only shows a title 'descending' and 'ascending':

[image]
I am already very tired of these and many other layout problems in Angular Material components, so I want to ask what could be wrong with styles, why do they work that crookedly?

Comment: Hi, it would be very useful if you provide more info.

1. What version of Material are you trying to use? Are you migrating to another version?
2. What is the context of your problem - are you using Angular for some time and suddenly styles stopped working because of some update, or you are new to Angular and nothing really works from the beginning?
3. Following to the previous one - how old is the application? (I'm thinking if maybe you may have some overriding styles or providers within the app, which you forgot about)
4. Did you imported all needed modules listed in the API docs?

Comment: 5. How did you define Angular theme? (In my case I had troubles with material styles when when migrating to material15 I forgot to modify theme file)

Comment: 1. angular/material": "^15.2.5" 2. I am new to Angular and nothing works from the beginning. 3. I don't know how old it is, I started working on this project after it was started. Your guess about ovveriding styles does make a sense, but root file 'styles.css' is empty and i don't know where to look else. 4. Yes and looks like even more than needed. 5. @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";